# Could not connect to host with https SOAP and ok with http

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I have difficulty to call my Soap web service with an `https`, before I had it in `http` and it works fine, now its changed to `https` and Im not able to call it:

the endPoint of SOAP content

```
<service name="someName">
    <port binding="tns:toto" name="somename123">
        <soap:address location="https://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:100xx/web/services/somename456/somename789"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

with http, I called it with success like this :

> ```
> <soap:address location="http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:100xx/x...
> ```

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);

$url = 'ws/wervice_web_info.xml';
$credentials = array('login' => 'someLogin', 'password' => 'somePassword');

$soap = new SoapClient($url, $credentials);
```

Now with https: I tried the bellow code but without success

> Error : Exception Thrown: Could not connect to host
>
> ```
> <soap:address location="https://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:100xx/x...
> ```

test:

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);

$url = 'ws/wervice_web_info.xml';
$my_cert_file = 'ws/certificate.pem";

$soap = new SoapClient($url, array('local_cert', $my_cert_file) );
```

Comment: Is https working without the Soap, i.e. do you have SSL certificates installed etc?

Comment: Maybe the service 1) doesn't support `HTTPS` or 2) maybe it isn't listening to `HTTPS` on the specified port `100xx`

Comment: @user3070485 yes, the url SOAP contain a ssl certificate

Comment: @Misantorp the server support the port, when I run `telnet https://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:100xx` I connect to the server with success

Comment: To my knowledge you will only test `HTTP` using `telnet`. What is the output of `openssl s_client -connect xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:100xx`

Comment: `CONNECTED(00000003) ...  CN = devlpts_CERTIFICATE_AUTHORITY
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain ... BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ...certificat content here.... No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-521, 521 bits `

Comment: Not that familiar with PHP, but you'll need to add trust to that self signed certifiate